# Django class based view - Thread Safe

Tags: django, multithreading

I have some experience on web applications in Java. In servlets, you have to declare class based attributes as final as its not thread safe..

When I try to compare with Django class based views. Is it safe to assume the below code is thread safe? I believe its thread safe but some one let me know the list of things that I need to take care for multi threaded applications in Django.

```
class MyFormView(View):
    form_class = MyForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'form_template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        person = Person()
        if form.is_valid():
            # <process form cleaned data>
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

## Edit-1

Created a new class and initiated within the POST method

Class Person(object):
     name = 'sample'

Comment: This is the first thing that is mentioned in Django doc for CBVs, that it's thread safe - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/#specification

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class attributes on class-based views are shared across all threads, and are generally not thread-safe. You should treat class attributes as read-only attributes, which is what Django does as well. This means you can set `initial` to a dictionary, but you should never modify this dictionary. The same is true for arguments passed to `View.as_view()`.

Instance attributes are thread-safe. Each time a view is invoked, a new instance of the view class is created, which is never shared across threads. This means you can set and modify instance attributes, such as `self.object`, without having to worry about concurrent threads.

Comment: THanks..In the above case...MyForm is could be different for each thread and looks like a class based attribute..How does Django manages this?

Comment: It is a class attribute, so you shouldn't change it. Instead, [`FormMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#formmixin) provides a `get_form_class()` method which you can override to return something other than `self.form_class`. Class-based views have many such methods you can override to provide context-dependant values.